# Make sure async methods execute in same order as they were called

Tags: ios, concurrency, nsurlconnection

Let's say I have 3 async methods which all do the same thing: send some data to a server and add the response data to an array (all of them add to the same array).

I call these methods at the same time, but they send different amounts of data to the server.

If the first method sends more data to the server than the third method, the third method will get the response back sooner, thus add the data to the array sooner. The response data consits of coordinates, so the order in which they are in the array matters.

How can I make sure, that even if the third method gets the repsonse sooner than the first or the second one, it won't add the data to the array before the previous methods did? Thus, preserving the order of the coordinates in the array.

The methods are `NSURLConnection`s and they all send an async request.

**EDIT**: Here is the working code:

```
 //Array of snapped points from the JSON
            NSArray *snappedPoints = [result objectForKey:@"snappedPoints"];

            NSMutableArray *locationsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            //Loop through the snapped points array and add each coordinate to a temporary array
            for (int i = 0; i<[snappedPoints count]; i++) {
                NSDictionary *location = [[snappedPoints objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"location"];

                double latitude = [[location objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
                double longitude = [[location objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

                CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];

                [locationsArray addObject:loc];

            }


            //Add these temporary location arrays to the dictionary with the key as the request number
            [tempLocationDictionary setObject:locationsArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",requestNumber]];

            //If all requests have completed get the location arrays from the dicitonary in the same order as the request were made
            if([tempLocationDictionary count] == numberOfRequests){

                //Just a path because I am drawing these coordinates on a map later
                GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];

                //Loop through the dictionary and get the location arrays in the right order
                for (int i = 0; i<[tempLocationDictionary count]; i++) {
                    //Create a dummy array
                    NSArray *array = [tempLocationDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i+1]];

                    //Get the coordinates from the array which we just got from the dictionary
                    for (CLLocation *location in array) {
                        [path addCoordinate:location.coordinate];

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Depends on what the methods are doing that makes them asynchronous. Are these `NSURLSession` calls? `NSOperationQueue`? Something else?

Comment: NSURLConnection with an async reauest!

Comment: Update your question with relevant code so people can point you in a good direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to replace `NSURLConnection` with `NSURLSession` and its related classes. It's newer and generally a superior choice. For your specific situation, it's possible to use a custom `NSURLSessionConfiguration` where you would set `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` to 1. That way the connections would be forced to run in order, solving your problem.

Of course, not having simultaneous connections might slow things down. In that case you'll have to accumulate the data temporarily *without* adding it to your array and only update the array when all the connections are complete. There are various ways you might do this depending on exactly what data comes back from the server.

One relatively simple way: If you know you'll always have three connections, use an `NSMutableDictionary` with integer `NSNumber` objects as the keys. After each connection you'd do something like

```
mutableDictionary[@1] = // your server data here
```

Use `@2` or `@3` for the other connections. Every time you add data, check to see if you have results for all three, and if so, add everything to your array. There are lots of other ways around this, the key is to have some kind of temporary structure where you can (a) accumulate data until all the connections are complete, and (b) keep track of which data came from which connection, either simply by number, or by URL, or by some other unique data that the server provides.

Comment: The latter half of this answer is what I had in mind and why I asked the OP to post some relevant code. Then a more concrete solution could be offered.

Comment: Thanks! I had something similar in my mind as well. The only problem was with (b) keeping track of which data came from which connection. I thought about assigning a number to each connection (increasing the number by one for each connection), and adding their data to the dictionary with the connection's assigned number. Than add the data to the array from the dictionary based on their keys, starting from number 1. Would this work?

Comment: Yes, indeed this idea worked. I updated the code to reflect this! Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem to be solved with NSOperationQueue and dependencies.

Check out [Advanced NSOperations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/) [[transcript](http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/226)] from WWDC 2015:

> When the WWDC app starts up, there's a bunch of setup that we need to do.
>
> First, we are going to download a small configuration file, and this file will tell us small things like what's the most recently supported version of the application, what features we have enabled, and so on.
>
> So after we download this file, we are going to perform a version check to make sure that you are running the latest version of the WWDC app.
>
> And then after we check the version of the app, we can start downloading useful pieces of information, such as the news that we show in the News tab and the schedule for the conference.
>
> After we've downloaded the schedule, then we can start importing any favorites that you've saved to iCloud, any feedback that you've submitted so you can see it in the app, and we are also going to start downloading the list of videos.

Applying dependencies as they describe for these operations should sort you nicely.

Comment: Its a useful technique and thanks for the pointer to the interesting presentation, but in this case I don't believe that there is a dependency between the three tasks, so Tom's suggestion of collating the data correctly after the operations complete will provide the required outcome with the benefit of concurrency

Comment: Your question said "How can I make sure, that even if the third method gets the repsonse sooner than the first or the second one, it won't add the data to the array before the previous methods did?". That means that operation SaveData3 has a dependency on SaveData1 and SaveData2 completing, correct?

Comment: It wasn't my question, but using dependencies on fetching the data is one way of achieving the required outcome, but so is managing how the data is put into the array once it is retrieved